# Generate PDF with TCPDF Library in Wordpress after Saving a Post

Tags: php, wordpress, tcpdf

I'm writing this thread because I cannot figure out why the code I've implemented in my Wordpress website doesn't generate the PDF using the TCPDF Library:

The library is inside the file manager and it is linked to the correct path.

In this version of the code I want to show the PDF in the browser after hitting the "Update Post" button to check if it works and if it correctly generate the PDF but nothing seems to happen after saving the post.

Can anyone helping me to figure out what's missing or if the code is not right? Thank you

```
<?php 
require_once(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/mu-plugins/tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); 

function generate_pdf_from_post($post_id) {
    // Get the post content
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $content = $post->post_content;
    
    // Create a new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    
    // Set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor($post->post_author);
    $pdf->SetTitle($post->post_title);
    
    // Remove default header/footer
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    
    // Set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    
    // Add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    
    // Write the post content to the PDF
    $pdf->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, '');
    
    // Output the PDF to the browser
    $pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
}

add_action('save_post', 'generate_pdf_on_save', 10, 3);

function generate_pdf_on_save($post_id, $post, $update) {
    if ($update) {
        // Only generate PDF if the post is being updated, not created
        $custom_post_types = array('properties_for_sale', 'vacation_rentals', 'long_term_rentals');
        if(in_array(get_post_type( $post_id ), $custom_post_types)){
          generate_pdf_from_post($post_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks correct and working at first sight. It uses the TCPDF library to generate a PDF from the content of a specific post. It also uses the "save_post" action to trigger the generation of the PDF when a post is updated. However, it is important to check if all the necessary information for running the script is available, for example, database connection information, configuration parameters for TCPDF, etc.